# How to make my bot skip over urls that don't exist

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey guys I was wondering if there was a way to make my bot skip invalid urls after 1 try to continue with the for loop but continue doesn't seem to work

```
def check_valid(stripped_results):
  global vstripped_results
  vstripped_results = []
  for tag in stripped_results:
    conn = requests.head("https://" + tag)
    conn2 = requests.head("http://" + tag)
    status_code = conn.status_code
    website_is_up = status_code == 200
    if website_is_up:
      vstripped_results.append(tag)
    else:
      continue
```

stripped results is an array of an unknown amount of domains and Subdomains which is why I have the 'https://' part and tbh I'm not even sure whether my if statement is effective or not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated I don't want to get rate limited by discord anymore from sending so many invalid domains through. :(

Comment: If you just want to know whether the domain is valid, you can simply use `socket.gethostbyname` to translate the domain to an IP address.  That won't tell you whether there is a web server there, but it will validate the host name.

Comment: Thank you Tim, now I discovered the socket module and I can get all the info I will eventually need @Tim Roberts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. To check the validity of a URL there exist a python library, namely `Validators`. This library can be used to validate any URL for if it exist or not. Let's take it step by step.

Firstly,
Here is the documentation link for validators:
https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

---

#### How do you validate a link using `validators`?

It is simple. Let's work on command line for a moment.

This image shows it. This module gives out boolean result on if it is a valid link or not.

[image: Command Line for Validators]

Here for the link of this question it gave out `True` and when it would be false then it would give you the error.

You can validate it using this syntax:

```
validators.url('Add your URL variable here')
```

Remember that this gives boolean value so code for it that way.

So you can use it this way...

---

I wouldn't be implementing it in your code as I want you to try it yourself once. I would help you with this if you are unable to do it.

Thank You! :)

Comment: This worked a simple and wonderful charm, loved the energy in the response and also fixed a bug I had even if I managed to get past this current problem before. If only you got paid for this XD @Bhavyadeep Yadav

Comment: Nope! Never Paid. Free Service Forever. xD @CrypticDev

Comment: And if it really helped you why not upvote it and accept this answer so that others don't waste their time answering it 
:D

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
def check_valid(stripped_results):
global vstripped_results
vstripped_results = []
for tag in stripped_results:
  conn = requests.head("https://" + tag)
  conn2 = requests.head("http://" + tag)
  status_code = conn.status_code
  website_is_up = status_code == 200
  if website_is_up:
    vstripped_results.append(tag)
  else:
    #Do the thing here
```

Comment: You didn't change anything just removed continue

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was the continue as you said there.

Comment: It's okay I probably didn't make it clear enough