# How to limit the amount of url connection retries my discord bot makes

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, discord.py

Hey guys I have been having this issue for a long time now and it is causing me to get rate limited by discord, I want my bot to try and find which urls are valid and work by sending requests to each one. However when it encounters a url that is invalid it keeps trying until max retries has been hit and sometimes getting me rate limited.

```
 check_valid(stripped_results):
  for tag in stripped_results:
    conn = requests.head("https://" + tag)
    conn2 = requests.head("http://" + tag)
    status_code = conn.status_code
    status_code2 = conn2.status_code
    website_is_up = status_code == 200
    website_is_up2 = status_code2 == 200
    if website_is_up or website_is_up2:
      vstripped_results.append(tag)
    else: 
      continue
```

My code shows the process of checking whether a url is valid or not and I need to add a process to skip an invalid url after about 3 tries, something low like that.
Any advice I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `requests` is a blocking library, please use `aiohttp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this question. You asked this already in another one so I would simply attach is here.

Link: [How to make my bot skip over urls that don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66946590/how-to-make-my-bot-skip-over-urls-that-dont-exist/66956308#66956308)

Thank You! :)